# Paste from Excel to Word keeping font colour

Tags: excel, vba

I copy and paste from Excel to Word using VBA.

I have one problem, the first cell of the table is black after it is pasted to Word. The title consists of two letters, first letter black and second letter red. I need the red for the second letter to reflect on Word.

I tried pastespecial code and the colour does appear, however, the formatting goes haywire and I would ideally like to retain using the pasteexceltable code if possible.

```
Sub contractDCN()

Sheets("Print").UsedRange.Clear
Sheets("DCN Inputs").Select

If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("DCN Inputs").Range("ProductToggle")) Then
    Sheets("DCN Master").Rows("1:26").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Print").Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
End If

If Sheets("DCN Inputs").Range("CouponOption").Value = "Fixed" Then
    Sheets("DCN Master").Rows("27:34").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Print").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
ElseIf Sheets("DCN Inputs").Range("CouponOption").Value = "Floating" Then
    Sheets("DCN Master").Rows("27:34").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Print").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("DCN Inputs").Range("ProductToggle")) Then
    Sheets("DCN Master").Rows("35:74").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Print").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If

Sheets("Print").Select

On Error Resume Next
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If obj Is Nothing Then
    Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
obj.Visible = True

Set objDoc = obj.Documents.Add
a = Sheets("Print").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Print").Range("A1:F" & a).Copy
objDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
objDoc.Activate

Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
With objTable
    .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
    .PreferredWidth = 505
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 3
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With objDoc.PageSetup
.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
End With

With objDoc
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpace1pt5
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 10
End With

Sheets("DCN Inputs").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This might sound silly, but won't you colour this specific range (second letter of table's first cell) in red?

Comment: Note: Using `On Error Resume Next` without error handling is a bad idea. This line hides *all* error messages until `End Sub` in your code, but the errors still occur you just cannot see them (you are kind of blind). Therefore you are not able to find your errors and you cannot debug/fix your code. Remove that line or implement a complete error handling instead.

Answer (score 0):

#### This will color second letter in first cell of first table

```
With objDoc.Range.Tables(1).Range.Cells(1).Range
    objDoc.Range(Start:=.Start + 1, _
                 End:=.Start + 2).Font.ColorIndex = 6
End With
```

**OR**

```
objDoc.Range.Tables(1).Range.Cells(1).Range.Characters(2).Font.ColorIndex = 6
```